# Sharepoint 2013 Search in Multilingual sites

Tags: search, search-results, language, multilingual

I created a Site and changed it to **Arabic** from the site. But when I am trying to Search any Content in Arabic it is displaying it as "*Nothing Matches here*". If I am searching the content in English, it is returning the results for the searched text. How can I Search the content in Arabic i.e. changing from default language to the selected language. Is there a work-around for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is because it is triggering a different search set and using the German setup, for this search it would appear you have to enforce English as the language and this is how you do it:

[2007]

I don't have a copy of 2007 running so from memory it is (I tried Googleing it but couldn't find a post on it):

Create a copy of the existing search results page.

Alter the new page to bypass the ACCEPT-LANGUAGE header which SharePoint uses to set the language.

Change the search options to use this new search results page instead.

[2010]

Go to the search results page as administrator

Put the page into edit mode and edit the core results web part

In Result Query Options change the Query Language to the preffered language.

If you want it to be multilingual this all comes down to language auto detection and the German language. The word breaker is the key here, it breaks words up for indexing and it does this in German very differently to English. The German specifics are here detailed in a kb issue with German search results. Unfortunately you are only just scratching the surface of search configuration for multilingual usage, an investigation into the words indexed by the crawler would possibly be a good way to go, you can create yourself a scope for each language you desire and look at the results that way.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/979514

Comment: Thanks for your reply Gowtham. But I don't find any 'Result query option' when I edited the web-part. Is there any other approaches to achieve this?